# Present a view on a specific occurrences

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a kind of a "alert view" wiche informs for example the user that he has disable is location services etc ..

Since this "alert view" only appears on specific occurrences thought of tow ways to do it the goal is to create something similar to that:
[image]

### V1:

to use the method:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
```

Then I would have to set for each asset in the viewcontroller the zPostion and so to determine where to set the "alert view". since it should be on top of all.And I would have to create the view complete in code.

### V2:

Is to create the "alert view" in the storyboard plus setting the specific constrains and alter the constrains during runtime

### edit:

```
@implementation OHAlertWindow
// Initialize the UIWindow subclass and put a UILabel inside it
- (id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        CGRect navigationBarFrame;
        CGRect statusBarFrame;
        UILabel *messageLabel;

        statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        navigationBarFrame = CGRectMake(statusBarFrame.origin.x, statusBarFrame.origin.y,
                                        statusBarFrame.size.width, statusBarFrame.size.height + 50);
        messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [messageLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [messageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelAlert]; // THIS IS IMPORTANT!!
        [self setAlpha:0.0f];
        [self setHidden:NO];
        [self setFrame:statusBarFrame];
        [self addSubview:messageLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

// Use singleton pattern so we only need one instance of the class
// throughout the whole app
+ (OHAlertWindow *)sharedInstance {

    static OHAlertWindow *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[OHAlertWindow alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
- (void)showWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f animations:^{
        [self setAlpha:1.0f];
    }];
}
```

@end

```
@implementation LaaxHomeViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [[OHAlertWindow sharedInstance]showWithMessage:@"test"] ;
}
@end
```

Comment: You cannot show custom UI elements on the iOS home screen. Or did you want to show it within your app? In that case, the screenshot you provided is misleading.

Comment: @ØyvindHauge yes it should be in app. The screenshot is just an example how it should look like

Comment: Ok, that makes way more sense. I have actually done something similar before. Let me post an answer.

Comment: Try setting the frame of the child uilabel at initialization (in the init method). E.g.: [_messageLabel setFrame:statusBarFrame];

Comment: @ØyvindHauge still not visible

Comment: Try moving the call to `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: @ØyvindHauge nope that did not do work ..

Comment: Please send me your project and i'll have a look. post@ohauge.net

Comment: @ØyvindHauge got a mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a navigation controller, `UINavigationItem` has the `prompt` property for displaying additional text above the nav bar buttons.

```
    self.navigationItem.prompt = "Location services are disabled"
```

[image]

Comment: thank for ur answer but I can not see anything and yes I am using a navigation controller

Comment: If you can't see anything you must be doing something wrong, try setting the prompt text after the controller is added to the nav controller stack.

Comment: It is fine to do it there, I can't see why it would not display for you if the view controller is pushed to a nav controller and the nav bar is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar functionality for a project I did some time a go. Here is how I solved it.

My solution was to subclass a `UIWindow`. Below is the most important parts of the implementation:

```
@implementation OHAlertWindow

...

// Initialize the UIWindow subclass and put a UILabel inside it
- (id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        navigationBarFrame = CGRectMake(statusBarFrame.origin.x, statusBarFrame.origin.y,
                                        statusBarFrame.size.width, statusBarFrame.size.height + kNavBarHeight);
        _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [_messageLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_messageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelAlert]; // THIS IS IMPORTANT!!
        [self setAlpha:0.0f];
        [self setHidden:NO];
        [self setFrame:statusBarFrame];
        [self addSubview:_messageLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

// Use singleton pattern so we only need one instance of the class
// throughout the whole app
+ (OHAlertWindow *)sharedInstance {

    static OHAlertWindow *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[OHAlertWindow alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
...

@end
```

And in my application I then call `[[OHAlertWindow sharedInstance] showWithMessage:@"hello World!"];` which will make the message appear above the navigation bar (I implemented the show method to fade the alpha value of the window for a nice effect).

Let me know if you have any questions!

**EDIT**

And here are the show/hide methods:

```
- (void)showWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    if(_isShowing) return;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kFadeInAnimDur animations:^{
        [self setAlpha:1.0f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kWaitDur
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(hide)
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }];
    [self setIsShowing:YES];
}

- (void)hide {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kFadeOutAnimDur animations:^{
        [self setAlpha:0.0f];
    }];
    [self setIsShowing:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks allot for ur answer one question where is statusBarFrame navigationBarFrame declared ? or better what are does  ?

Comment: They are declared as ivars in the uiwindow subclass like so: @implementation OHAlertWindow {
    CGRect navigationBarFrame;
    CGRect statusBarFrame;
}

I excluded it from the initial answer :)

Comment: ohh i SEE !! nice so for example now if I want to present a message i can go in any viewcontroller and call for example in viewdidload [[OHAlertWindow sharedInstance] showWithMessage:@"hello World!"]; ?

Comment: @TamoDaleko Exactly! Just import "OHAlertWindow.h" in your view controller and you are all set.

Comment: @TamoDaleko Just set the alpha value of the ohalertwindow to 1.0 in the init method and it will be showing constantly (and you will have to remove the call to the hide method in the show method).

Comment: my issue is that the I dont see anything ... I will update my answer